# CSS stop children overflowing parent in grid scroll

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a root container that is `100%` width and height. The root container is `overflow-x:scroll`.

Inside the root container is another container which has `n` number of fixed width elements. The container is `display:grid` with `grid-auto-flow:column`

The problem I have is that the container does not expand to fill the width of its children elements. This is evident when setting a background to the container. When the root container scrolls, the containers background cuts off.

You can see this clearly in the following codepen.
https://codepen.io/ozzyg/pen/YzObrqM

How would I get the container to be the width of its children?

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to decipher what your asking based on your question without specifics. If you could add in some class names your referring to it would help, but I think what you want is the following.

declare the width of your `.kalendar-dates` container. I would use

```
.kalendar-dates{width:fit-content}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: flex;` to `.kalendar`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

html, body {
  margin:0; padding:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

.kalendar {
  display: flex; /*  */
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #ffffff 25%, #e3f8ff 25%, #e3f8ff 50%, #ffffff 50%, #ffffff 75%, #e3f8ff 75%, #e3f8ff 100%);
  background-size: 56.57px 56.57px;
}

.kalendar-dates {
  height:100px;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;

  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #ffffff 25%, #f4e3ff 25%, #f4e3ff 50%, #ffffff 50%, #ffffff 75%, #f4e3ff 75%, #f4e3ff 100%);
  background-size: 56.57px 56.57px;
}

.kalendar-column {
  width:100px;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;

  background-image: linear-gradient(17deg, #ffffff00 25%, #cba8e3 25%, #cba8e3 50%, #ffffff00 50%, #ffffff00 75%, #cba8e3 75%, #cba8e3 100%);
  background-size: 136.81px 41.83px;
}
```

```html
<div class="kalendar"><div class="kalendar-dates"><div class="kalendar-column"></div><div class="kalendar-column"></div><div class="kalendar-column"></div><div class="kalendar-column"></div><div class="kalendar-column"></div><div class="kalendar-column"></div><div class="kalendar-column"></div><div class="kalendar-column"></div><div class="kalendar-column"></div><div class="kalendar-column"></div><div class="kalendar-column"></div><div class="kalendar-column"></div><div class="kalendar-column"></div><div class="kalendar-column"></div><div class="kalendar-column"></div><div class="kalendar-column"></div><div class="kalendar-column"></div><div class="kalendar-column"></div><div class="kalendar-column"></div><div class="kalendar-column"></div><div class="kalendar-column"></div><div class="kalendar-column"></div><div class="kalendar-column"></div><div class="kalendar-column"></div><div class="kalendar-column"></div></div></div>
```